# How to cut text in (insert) SELECT mode in Vim without unwanted behavior?

Tags: vim, cut, keymapping

I'm currently using this key mapping in my `.vimrc` file to simulate the Windows Cut  keyboard shortcut. Cut, meaning copy and delete the selected text.

`vnoremap <C-X> "+x`

This key mapping is part of the `mswin.vim` script that ships with Vim, which i don't use, i only use a few key mapping from that file.

When i then select text from within Vim in insert mode and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> the text is copied and deleted but with the unwanted side effect of the cursor moving several characters back and performing Vim's normal behavior of a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> press which is to decrement the number directly under the cursor!

For example, if i want to change the following code to cut the second occurrence of the word `Renderer` i start with this:

```
Renderer.setClearColorHex(0x7DB6D5, 1.0);
Renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
```

and end up with this:

```
Renderer.setClearColorHex(0x7DB6D5, 1.-1);  // <--- oh dear!
.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
```

Which causes more than a few bugs!

Is there anyway to avoid this unwanted behaviour with this keymap or is there another, safer way to Cut text in insert (SELECT) mode?

Comment: Do you use the **mouse** to select?

Comment: Yes, i do use the mouse to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a conflict with the Snipmate plugin in file `snipmate\after\plugin\snipMate.vim`.

I commented out these lines and all is fine.

```
" snor <bs> b<bs>
" snor <right> <esc>a
" snor <left> <esc>bi
" snor ' b<bs>'
" snor ` b<bs>`
" snor % b<bs>%
" snor U b<bs>U
" snor ^ b<bs>^
" snor \ b<bs>\
" snor <c-x> b<bs><c-x>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually use `mswin.vim` or not? AFAIK, a lot of things are done there in order to allow editing in *INSERT* mode and all that kind of monstrosity; if you only take one little snippet out there's no guarantee it will work correctly.

If you use MSWIN compatibility *and* this mapping is already in `mswin.vim`, why did you put it in your `vimrc`?

If you don't use MSWIN compatibility, there are many wrong things here:

- "editing" text is not done in *INSERT* mode, you **must** go back to *NORMAL* mode and perform your editing there
- when in *NORMAL* mode, `d` is the correct equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> as it deletes what you want it to delete and puts it into the default register, ready to be pasted somewhere else.
- you don't need to select a word to delete it, supposing you are on the `R` of `Renderer`, you should do `dw` to delete until the end of the current word

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: The way "to avoid this unwanted behaviour" is to use Vim as intended. Anyway, I've tried to replicate your problem with no (bad)luck: `<C-x>` successfully cuts the selected content without decrementing anything. Maybe you could try with `snoremap` instead of `vnoremap` since you are not in *VISUAL* mode but in *SELECT* mode. Also, allow me to repeat my question: do you use `mswin.vim` or not? And another request: could you paste your `vimrc` so that we can see if anything is in conflict?

Comment: What your mapping (`"+x`) is supposed to do is "delete given text and put it in register `+`". Instead, it does "delete given text and put it in register `+` and go up one line and decrement the first number on the right of the cursor": `"+xk<C-x>`. That's too weird, maybe you have other interfering mappings?

Comment: Are you going to provide the additional info I'm asking for or not?